# Unable to output to TCP through avconv

Tags: avconv

I'm trying to use avconv to read a video from disk and output it over a socket, using:

```
avconv -i video.mp4 tcp://127.0.0.1:5005
```

I get the error "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5005'."

What is the correct way to use `avconv` to stream TCP?

Answer (score 1):

According to

```
https://libav.org/avconv.html#tcp
```

you need to add a f parameter specifying the format:

```
avconv -i input -f format tcp://hostname:port?listen
```